# I require advice on a recurring problem with my brakes

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I've had a bike with hydraulic brakes for about six months now, and have a problem with the brake just losing power. I think it's fluid being lost.

This is a question I asked earlier 
[Something wrong with my brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66677/something-wrong-with-my-brakes)

I went back to the store and complained and spoke to the manager who gave me a free bleed and new brake pads. After not using my bike at all this quarantine me and my family decide to go out as we haven't been out the house in five weeks. I go to get my bike to find that there is no braking whatsoever. My lever is pushed all the way to the handlebar grips and there is no braking whatsoever for both front and back. I have all the receipts of all the pads I have bought from then and of the purchase and of the bleed.

What do I do now?

Comment: Where are you storing the bike? If you are losing all the fluid it should be on the bike or ground.

Comment: You aren't hanging the bike upside down, are you?

Comment: Or by the front wheel to a hook vertically to the wall?

Comment: No its horizontal leaning against my living room wall the floor to wheel angle would be like nearly 90° I ain't even turning it upside down or anything.Even when I'm cleaning it I put it the right way up it's never upside down or at an angle.Thats the thing I ain't doing anything wrong I just dont understand wtf is going on

Comment: Okay so I moved my wheel so the part that was on the actual brake system was out and there is oil on the top of the disk so the slide of it (the thin side)